How to install android sdk into my local machine for integrating aws waf managed rule with my mobile app
How to install android sdk into my local machine for integrating aws waf managed rule with my mobile app. The sdk for managing aws service is separate or same?.

AWS SDK for managing AWS services (like S3, DynamoDB, etc.) is separate from the AWS WAF Mobile SDK. Check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-mobile-sdk-installing.html

Yes @BobSmith. But I can't find that. I have raised a request with AWS support, but they have not responded yet.

Generate a ticket from this link https://support.console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create

Yes, I did. We don't have developer support option. But i have raised in account support. No answer yet.

You did few things wrong I guess select "Case type : Technical" and "Severity : Production system down". After that there is option of email and chat . There choose chat . Install Amazon Chime meeting and Share problem with realtime support agent and if they ask you can have option to do call and share your system screen as well.
